# Uploading html file generated from R-animation package to wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, r

I created a HTML file using the *animation* package in R.  Now I'm trying to upload the resulting HTML file to a wordpress blog but don't really know how to make it work.  It seems like I might need to upload some js or css files too but am not sure.  Also, it seems like I might need to upload the original data files as the HTML file is 2.5kb and the original CSV file is 2500kb.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have addressed this issue in `?saveHTML` if you are using the latest version of the **animation** package (the second paragraph in the `Note` section). Perhaps it is still not clear (I'll improve it in the next version), so let me explain it here:

What you need to upload are: the HTML file, the image folder, js and css. The CSV data is not required, since the animation is independent with the data now.

Comment: I think this maybe more of a wordpress question.  I'm not sure of where to upload files and folders to and also what code to use to show the animation.

Comment: OK, I see. Do you have FTP access to your host? You can upload all the files via FTP to the common place where WP puts the uploaded files: `wp-content/uploads/...`, or any other places that you think are convenient for you to write the URL pointing to the HTML animation file.

Comment: Yes, the HTML file and css, js and images folders were uploaded to that wp-content/uploads/... file.  Do I just copy the contents of the HTML file into the Wordpress HTML editor or is there more? Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, I see what you really mean now. The simplest way is to add a link to that html file in your Wordpress post. If you want to embed the animations in your post, it is not straightforward unless you are familiar with HTML: you can open the html file and replace the relative paths with the real URL's in your website, e.g. `images/` may need to be replaced by `http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/.../images/`. You have to make sure the JS code is not mangled by Wordpress editor. Finally copy the HTML code in your WP post.